# Datatable Redraw with New Data Issue

Tags: angularjs, datatables

> While redraw datatable with new data error occur.

```js
        var table = $('.classname').DataTable();
        table.clear().draw();
        table.rows.add($scope.somelist);        
        table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

> Error
>   DataTables warning: table id=tablename- Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

**Please Help Me**

Comment: Please try to assign an ID to your table and use `var table = $('#YOUR_ID').DataTable();`

Comment: I tried that way also. but same error.

Comment: Ok, so probably it's the value of `$scope.somelist` that is in a bad format. Sorry.

Comment: Thank You for your responce decadenza. While page load it's working perfectly. But in search condition it's not binding. I check data in both result which get. Both results are valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I've some groundwork for you, might this will take out from this.

```
var table = $('.classname').DataTable();
var arrData = $scope.somelist;//First check for proper JSON array
table.clear().draw();
table.rows.add([arrData]);//If data not into proper JSON array        
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Just check it and let me if it does not work!

Comment: Can you provide data from `$scope.somelist`?